# Multiple check box's and Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes (26). Their ids are "check-box-1", "check-box-2" etc.

How can I make these checkboxes work in code `$('#check-box-XXX').prop('checked', true);` so script (or css) will add automatically become #check-box-1 or #check-box-2 according to the link address?
Here is the code: http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/XJpLBK
Here is also a picture of what is needed. http://eyes.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Accordion.png

Comment: You need to better explain the problem. Your problem is in the css selector?

Comment: yes, it is. I guess it's about selector.

Comment: try this then, input[type=checkbox]:checked

Comment: Not it.

$('#check-box-PLACE FOR A NUMBER').prop('checked', true);
How to make it auto place the needed id. For example: 
<input name="radio" type="checkbox" id="check-box-26"/>
And when link goes to this position, it adds .prop('checked', true);

Comment: Looks like what you need is Javascript. You want it to when a user scrolls the page to auto check the checkbox, is that it?

Comment: As clear as gods' morning. Yes. 8)

Comment: I've post the code in the answer, see if it works. And next time try to be more specific in the title and the question ;)

Comment: seeing the associated HTML for the checkboxes as well would be handy - or even a partial jsfiddle

Comment: added the code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's see if this helps,

First you save the position of all the checkboxes related to the window:

```
var i = 0,
    lb = $('label[for*=check-box]'),
    ck = $('input[type=checkbox]'),
    len = lb.length,
    lbPos = definePositions();

function definePositions(){
    var i = 0,
        pos = [];
    // save the positions of the labels into an array
    for(;i<len;i++){ // iterate through the array with all of the checkboxes in order to save their position
        pos[i] = lb.eq(i).offset().top; // this gives you the current position of the label
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Then, you bind the event scroll to the window, and every time the user scrolls the page, it'll check if any of the checkboxes position is less or equal to the current scroll of the window. 
If it is true it'll check the box, otherwise it'll check false.

```
// bind the page scroll event and check for the positions
$(window).unbind('scroll').scroll(function() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop();
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){ // iterate through the array with all the positions of the checkboxes
        if(lbPos[i]<=s){ // if the position of the checkbox is less or equal to current scroll
            ck.eq(i).prop('checked', true); // prop the checkbox for true to open
        }else{
            ck.eq(i).prop('checked', false); // fallback to false to all other checkboxes
        }
    }
    lbPos = definePositions(); // redefine the label positions, since it changes with the accordion
});
```

Comment: What positions do I have to save? Dont understand.

Comment: If you have time: here is the site http://convertizer.biz/cabinet/task=onboarding
its in Russian, but I made accordion option and link in it in English - "Click here". I dont'understand how to make it work. Like I'm dumb. Maybe if you can see what I want... You can help me.

Comment: Also there is CSS attr [id^="check-box-"]. Is it possible to make smt like this to make working in JS or Jquery?

Comment: delete the code that I gave you and let me see the site without javascript errors, so I can test it ;)

Comment: Deleted. But not the whole site is under my construction, so 1 error as a present *). Also made 1 link on "Click here" as I want it to be.

Comment: Ok, I've corrected the code, It's in the answer... I don't know why but I had to change the position givers to the labels and so, when the scroll reaches the label the checkbox will prop true. you can test it using $('input[type=checkbox]').eq(0).prop('checked'); then scroll down an test it again. I believe It's what you need.

Comment: Ehm... it opens all checkboxes since middle of section. Can this code make open only one checkbox according to the link? as I made it before? The truth is near.

Comment: Kup, thank you so much for wasting your time solving this question, but it's not what is needed. The checkboxes open when appear on viewport... but i need the checkbox to be opened when the link is clicked: <a href="hello_text>Hello text!</a> - after click it goes to #hello_text and opens the checkbox. Sorry once again for wasting your time.